# Firebase Cloud messaging service key not working correctly

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Is the Firebase cloud messaging key present at the following two places same? 
1) Firebase Console -> Settings -> cloud messaging
2) google-services.json under api_key-> current_key

My project has different keys at both the places. I am unable to send any messages to my server post migration to FCM

Comment: if the answer is complete could you accept it as valid ?

Answer (score 0):

The **API-KEY** for sending FCM messages is the key present in:

```
Firebase Console -> Settings -> cloud messaging
```

The apy_key written in google_services.json is not used for FCM.

Comment: Which one? Server Key? Web Key? None of them is working.

**Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.**